# Bad messages handling with jms:message-driven-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I see one issue today.I have few messages dropped in a queue and one message is throwing error in service activator. the errorred message keep on trying again and again without other messages are processing from a queue. Is there any way I can set in below config to send error msg to end of queue messages. (ex if queue depth is 1000, error msg will be at 1000 pos)

```
 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="exch" destination="requestQueue"   channel="jmsInChannel" 
                            transaction-manager="txManager" acknowledge="auto" concurrent-consumers="3"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="jmsInChannel" ref="messageService"/>
```

Pls advice.

thanks Gary..Unfortunately we can't change any MQ configuration.

I have tried as follows and going to add service activator for errorRetryChannel.

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="jmsInChannel" ref="messageService">
         <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <int:retry-advice max-attempts="4" recovery-channel="errorRetryChannel">
                <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="5.0" maximum="60000" />
            </int:retry-advice>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would configure the broker to dump "poison" messages to a dead letter queue after some number of attempts.

If you can't do that, you can add a [retry advice to your service activator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) together with a recoverer that can log and otherwise dispose of the bad message.

A custom recoverer could requeue the message at the tail of the queue but you will probably want to trash irrecoverable messages.

Comment: Just want to update you in the documentation there is a int:retry-advice id="retrier" field, but Integration not allowing this. Without this i'm able to run application with no errors.